# How to perform a full backup of a MySql\MariaDB database?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, rdbms

how can I perform a full backup of a MariaDB (MySql) database (I mean tables creation and data inside these tables)?

I connect to this database using command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do this would be to use [`mysqldump`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysqldump/):

> The mysqldump client (...) can be used to dump a database or a collection of databases for backup or transfer to another database server (not necessarily MariaDB or MySQL). The dump typically contains SQL statements to create the table, populate it, or both. However, mysqldump can also be used to generate files in CSV, other delimited text, or XML format.

It can be used like this:

```
$ mysqldump db_name > backup-file.sql
```

You probably already have it installed, as it is one of the default command-line tools.

Comment: it is important to use the -R Option **"Include stored routines (procedures and functions) for the dumped databases in the output. This option requires the SELECT privilege for the mysql.proc table."** and also  --single-transaction: **"In this case, the logs are flushed only once, corresponding to the moment that all tables are locked by FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK."** see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_databases

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-methods.html this is ufficial reference for backup